# How to declare and initialise an array in Swift

Tags: variables, swift, declaration

I have a class in Swift that I'm trying to write that has a variable of an array of objects. Is there a better way to write this?

```
var myvar: Array<MyClass> = Array<MyClass>()
```

Without the bit after the = sign, the compiler complains about my AppDelegate having no initializers. The above way seems a bit lengthy (though it's no more terse than the c# equivalent, I guess). I'd just like to know if there's a shortcut. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can initialize the variable with an empty array:

```
var myvar: Array<MyClass> = []
```

or use automatic type inference:

```
var myvar = Array<MyClass>()
```

In addition, you can write `Array<MyClass>` as `[MyClass]`.

Comment: Thanks. I've now got it down to this: var myvar = [MyClass]()

Comment: Is any one of them better than the other? If so, why?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: `[MyClass]` is preferred over `Array<MyClass>`, see https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html: *“Although the two forms are functionally identical, the shorthand form is preferred ...”* –  `var myvar: [MyClass] = []` and `var myvar = [MyClass]()` are both fine, that is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 16):

```
To create an empty array or dictionary, use the initialiser syntax.

let emptyArray = [String]()
let emptyDictionary = [String: Float]()

let individualScores = [75, 43, 103, 87, 12]

let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
```