# Creating an array of a custom class and initializing it question

Tags: arrays, swift

I have created a custom class in swift called Article Class.
I have a question. can someone thoroughly explain what each of the following statement is doing:

```
var articles:[ArticleClass]? = []

articles = [ArticleClass]()
```

Comment: They both do the same thing. The second one does it with type inference. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718596/how-to-declare-and-initialise-an-array-in-swift/25718684#comment104051440_25718684

Answer (score 0):

`var articles:[ArticleClass]? = []` is declaring a variable of type Optional Array of ArticleClass  `[ArticleClass]?` and then it assigns a value of an empty Array of Article Class `[]`. This means that 'articles' is a list of ArticleClass and it's now empty (a list with no items in it).
Since it's optional, it can also have a nil value instead of a list.
For example, you can write this: `articles = nil` and it's valid.

`articles = [ArticleClass]()` is assigning an empty Array of ArticleClass to the variable 'articles'.
This line in this context is useless beacuse you have already assigned an empty array in the first line.

Comment: so basically they have the same function? which is assigning an empty array?